# .NET Forms Authentication with no timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

How can I set up [forms authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx) with no timeout?
I read across multiple sites that it's not recommended to use a high value in `timeout`, so I'm wondering how can I set up my forms so that the only way users can sign out is through the sign out button.
I know there is `slidingExpiration` and I can create a persistent cookie but in this case I'm dealing with a single page app where users just have to edit fields in a GridView and all that it's made with AJAX, so unless I refresh the page with some meta refresh tag (which I don't want to) I'm having a hard time overcoming this challenge.

What can I do?

And if I want to persist the session across different browsers how can I achieve that? [SqlMembershipProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set some properties in the web.config file.
Here you can edit the timeout property.
Check this website https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61(v=vs.100).aspx